# need to check whether the has code session is set or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Hi i have a form in which user is sent invite code ..everything is working properly ..the hash code is set using session..

now i want certain users to register without has code..so want to set condition if hash code is not set..but i am not able to get it solved....can anyone give me any idea to fix this?

This is the action which i need to set if session has code is not..i tried using if loop but i am getting error

```
class VendorsController < ApplicationController

  def invited_new
    @user_invitation = UserInvitation.where(hash_code: session[:hash_code]).first
    #raise ArgumentError "Cannot find invitation with hash_code #{session[:hash_code]}" unless @user_invitation.present?
    @vendor = Vendor.new(user: current_user, vendor_type: @user_invitation.invitation_type)
    @vendor.build_address
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you please use google translate?

Comment: sorry for that... i am new to ror. in the above action i need to check whether session hash code is set or not...i used if els loop but i am getting error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
class VendorsController < ApplicationController

  def invited_new
    if session[:hash_code] && UserInvitation.where(hash_code: session[:hash_code]).any?
      # logic for users with hash_code
    else
      #logic for users without hash_code
    end
  end

end
```

This should check first if there is `hash_code` in session then for this `hash_code` if there are [any?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-any-3F) (one or more) `UserInvitation`